# Ansible - Combine into list

Tags: ansible

Say i have an object like this:

```
groups:
  - name: grp1
    location: newyork
  - name: grp2
    location: newhork
  - name: grp3
    location: paris
```

And I would like to have:

```
locations:
  newyork:
  - grp1
  - grp2
  paris:
  - grp3
```

I've tried the combine filter but I can't get lists with that. I just get:

```
newyork: grp2
paris: grp3
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us your playbook.

Comment: Also, don't name your variable `groups`, because this is the name of an Ansible built-in variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```yaml
- name: set fact for locations
  set_fact:
    locations: "{{ locations | default({}) | combine({item.location: locations[item.location] | default([]) + [item.name]}) }}"
  loop: "{{ my_groups }}"
```

I used this as the input:

```yaml
vars:
  locations: {}
  my_groups:
    - name: grp1
      location: newyork
    - name: grp2
      location: newyork
    - name: grp3
      location: paris
```

Ansible provides your desired output:

```yaml
  locations:
    newyork:
    - grp1
    - grp2
    paris:
    - grp3
```

Answer (score 1):

Group the list by *location*

```yaml
  arr: "{{ grps|groupby('location') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  arr:
    - - newyork
      - - {location: newyork, name: grp1}
        - {location: newyork, name: grp2}
    - - paris
      - - {location: paris, name: grp3}
```

Create the dictionary

```yaml
  locations: "{{ dict(arr|map('first')|
                      zip(arr|map('last')|
                              map('map', attribute='name'))) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  locations:
    newyork: [grp1, grp2]
    paris: [grp3]
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    grps:
      - {location: newyork, name: grp1}
      - {location: newyork, name: grp2}
      - {location: paris, name: grp3}

    arr: "{{ grps|groupby('location') }}"
    locations: "{{ dict(arr|map('first')|
                        zip(arr|map('last')|
                                map('map', attribute='name'))) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: arr|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: locations|to_yaml
```